# Multi Value Parameter Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am creating a report that gives details about our work order estimates (Labor, Materials, and Equipment).

Since the information is coming from 4 different tables that have a many to many relationship, I have created multiple sub reports.

On the main report I created a `parameter` that allows multiple values and prompts the user to enter work order IDs. I passed the parameter to all the sub reports. My problem is on the `materials sub report`.

I created a summary of cost and grouped it by `work order id`, so I could get a total for materials on each work order. Then I created a formula for a restock fee that is conditional on work order type. If it's a water, sanitary, or storm work order then there is a **10% restocking fee**, otherwise there is **none**. I then added a summary for cost that wasn't grouped to get a total for all work orders.

The problem comes when I try to create a formula to add the report summary to the Restock formula. It only adds the restock fee for the last work order entered, not all of them. I realize that the multi value parameter is an array, but how do I get the restock formula to include the fees for all work orders that were entered?

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3yoI.png]

Comment: Can you post the formula?

Comment: The formula for the restock fee is as follows: if {WORKORDER.ASSETGROUP} in ["Water", "Storm", "Sanitary"]
then Sum ({MATERIALCOSTPRJ.COST}, {MATERIALCOSTPRJ.WORKORDERID})* .10
else 0.00

Comment: When I create a formula to add the report summary of cost to the restock fee, it only adds the 31.41, not the restock fees for the other workorders.